# windows phone 8 download file and use its path

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, file-transfer

I've been looking at file transfer tutorials for windows phone 8, but for some reason they all seem quite code extensive for what i want, wich is simply to download a file(image in this case) to the phone and use the path its been saved too as a source of a  control

i get the following Json from a webservice

```
[{"name":"image1.png","link":"http://www.xxxxxx.com/image1.png"},{"name":"image2.png","link":"http://www.xxxxxx.com/image1.jpg"}]
```

and want to use those links to do the downloads

in sum i want to 
Check if file exists, if not download, and get its path to use later.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to parse the JSON, I would recommend Newtonsoft JSON for that.
After that you need to check if file exists. (You could use the MD5 of the URL as the filename for localstorage and check if there is a file with the name)
If the file does not exist you need to use a HttpWebRequest to download the file and then save it to the isolated storage.

EDIT:
To check if file exists:

```
IsolatedStorageFile localStorage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();
if(localStorage.FileExists("image1.png"))
    //use cached version
```

WebRequest:

```
WebRequest req = HttpWebRequest.Create("http://domain.com/image.png");
WebResponse res = await GetResponseAsync(req);
if (res != null)
{
    Stream rspStream = res.GetResponseStream();
    //save stream to isolated storage
}
```

GetResponseAsync:

```
private static Task<HttpWebResponse> GetResponseAsync(WebRequest request)
{
    var taskComplete = new TaskCompletionSource<HttpWebResponse>();
    request.BeginGetResponse(asyncResponse =>
    {
        try
        {
            HttpWebRequest responseRequest = (HttpWebRequest)asyncResponse.AsyncState;
            HttpWebResponse someResponse = (HttpWebResponse)responseRequest.EndGetResponse(asyncResponse);
            taskComplete.TrySetResult(someResponse);
        }
        catch (WebException webExc)
        {
            HttpWebResponse failedResponse = (HttpWebResponse)webExc.Response;
            taskComplete.TrySetResult(failedResponse);
        }
    }, request);
    return taskComplete.Task;
}
```

Comment: i already do the parsing of the json all i need is the methods to checkif file exists in localstorage and if not download it

Comment: i see, what if the file doesn't exist?, wich is what im really interested on

Comment: Just add an "else" and use a HttpWebRequest to dowload the file and then save it to the isolatedstorage.

Comment: yes, i know that ehhe
what i don't know is how to use the HttpWebRequest to download the file, if you could post that part of the code would be great :)

Comment: thanks :)
.
for some reason i get that GetResponseAsync doesnt not exist in the current context error :\

Comment: added that to my answer.

Comment: if it wasnt to much to ask , could you add the //save stream to isolated storage part, and a example of //use cached version

Comment: I'm sorry, but stackoverflow is not for code sharing, it's to help each other with solution approaches and not to write code for someone else. Saving a stream to the isolated storage is not that complex and a search for that should provide you many solutions! Same thing for using the cached version. Just search for "windows phone 8 bind to isolated storage path" or something similar.